# How WhatsApp send audio files or video clips instantly?

Tags: applications, whatsapp-messenger

When I try to forward any video clips that I downloaded to my phone from any other contact it sends immediately (ie without any uploading) . Also attaching some mp3 files are also sent instantly without showing any delay in uploading? How is this possible? I think they are storing all media files on their server.

Comment: So whats the question?

Comment: @sameer The question is clear

Comment: @sameer How whatsapp avoid uploading?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about inner-workings of a 3rd-party app. It is best to forward such questions to the app's developers.

Comment: @Chahk That's not one of the reasons listed in [help/off-topic]. It's possible that the answer is explained somewhere online (say, in a development blog, or an interview with one of the developers) so it could be answered here. Even if the answer isn't currently known, if Mr Jacob does what you suggest, he can always come back and answer the question himself.

Comment: @DanHulme That is not listed as a reason directly, but the fact is that the question is Android-independent. The same behaviour occurs in all platforms of Whatsapp. Therefore in my opinion it's as much off-topic as are (for example) questions about Whatsapp group admins (which we've seen plenty) or games on Android (specifically gameplay-related questions).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess that's because whatsapp stores attachments on their database with its own checksum (every file can be represented by an alphanumeric sequence of characters called like this).
When you try to upload a file whose checksum is already on their database, they just use the uploaded copy of the file. 
This leads to several advantages. Indeed, preventing double uploads:

- Avoids server overloads
- Makes you save mobile data
- Make whatsapp save space on their database

Comment: Sometimes, If I share some mp3 files or any music files from my phone, it will be sent immediately even if I didn't receive that file through whatsapp. Same checksum is used, rite?

Comment: Yes, this system works if any whatsapp user ever shared this file

Comment: Dropbox does the same thing.

Comment: Does this mean that whatsapp can decrypt and see the images being shared?